# Negative angles not working properly when rotating a wheel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, clamp

So I have a steering wheel, which turns with A and D buttons. I have clamped it on a negative and positive angle. I also have a code that returns the wheel to it's original rotation when the angle is not zero and not pressing anything. I also have a code that slows the rotation when the wheel is close to the clamped angle.

Here's my code for the wheel returning to it's original position. The value of the rotateBack is half the amount because of a bug where the wheel gets stuck to a negative angle if A and D are pressed at the same time.

```
if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") <1 && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) == false && !(angle < 1))
    {
        angle += rotateBack * Time.deltaTime;
        if (angle > 0 )
        {
            rotateBack = -600f;
        }
        
        
    }

    

    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0 && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) == false && !(negativeangle < 1))
    {
        angle += rotateBack * Time.deltaTime;
        if (negativeangle > 0)
        {
            rotateBack = 300;
        }
```

Here's the (bad) fix to the bug:

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) == false&& Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) == false && negativeangle > 5)
    {
        angle += rotateBack * Time.deltaTime;
        rotateBack = 300f;
    }
```

The rotation to the right, where angles are positive, work as they should. But when turning left, the wheel ignores the slowing when close to the clamped angle, and when the wheel is turned to max, the wheel shakes and isn't stable. It goes over the clamped angle. I've noticed that the less powerful pc I have, the more it shakes and is unbalanced.

Here's my clamping code. There's negativeangle, but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
angle = Mathf.Clamp(-120, angle, 120);
    
    angle = Mathf.Clamp(120, -120, angle);
    wheel.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
```

And here is the code when the wheel slowed down when nearing the clamping angle. It doens't work on negative angles.

```
    if (angle < 100||negativeangle>100)
    {
        
        angle += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 500;
        

    }
    if (angle>80||negativeangle>80)
    {
        
        angle += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 5;
        
    }

    if (angle > 100||negativeangle > 100)
    {
        
        angle += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime * 1;
        
    }
```

I've tried fixing this by changing the angle to a negative angle, which is read as a positive angle, but it doesn't fix the problem.

```
if (angle < 0)
    {
        negativeangle = -angle;
    }
```

How can I fix the wheel going over clamped angle and shaking, and so that the wheel slows down when past a certain angle on the left side? Everything else works on the wheel except these things.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use separate variables for `angle` and `negativeangle`, this will only make your code more confusing and make it hard to fix bugs like this. Instead, you should have a single `angle` variable, which may be positive or negative.

I would suggest that you write your update function like this:

```cs
private void UpdateWheel() {
    // Get the input direction (using GetAxis, GetKey, etc.)
    // Negative values are left, positive values right.
    float input = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    if (input == 0f) {
        // No input - return to the original position
        if (angle != 0f) {
            const float returnSpeed = 600f;
            float newAngle = angle - returnSpeed * Time.deltaTime * Mathf.Sign(angle);

            if (Mathf.Sign(angle) != Mathf.Sign(newAngle))
                angle = 0f;
            else
                angle = newAngle;
        }
    }
    else {
        // Move the wheel in the input direction
        const float maxAngle = 120f;

        float absAngle = Mathf.Abs(angle);
        float inputSpeedFactor;

        if (absAngle <= 80f)
            inputSpeedFactor = 500f;
        else if (absAngle <= 100f)
            inputSpeedFactor = 5f;
        else
            inputSpeedFactor = 1f;

        angle = Mathf.Clamp(angle + input * inputSpeedFactor * Time.deltaTime, -maxAngle, maxAngle);
    }

    wheel.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
}
```

Also, you are not using the [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) function correctly, the order of the arguments is (value, min, max).

Comment: I think the main issue is probably the misuse of `Clamp` .. you should move that to the top of the answer